# Extracting a string containing given number of characters, from a text file

Tags: python

My text file contains data consisting of numerous entries, with each entry start with the character `<`.

By using python, I want to extract data in such a way that only the first five characters of each entry is extracted (in addition to  `<`).
For example:

```
my file= [<1
acloclscloclxcccdddddddddddcccccddddddddddddweeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
  <2
lsjfljljljljljljlsjdfojljljlholhowljljljljouopuljlj
  <3
ljlhohouojljljjouopuljljljhlhouljljlhh
  <4
hououojljljlhouojljljljlhouljljljljoukhklhkhkh......]
```

And the result I want should be the file containing only `<` and first 5 chagacters i.e.

```
 <1
aclo
  <2
lsjf
  <3
ljlh
  <4
houo
```

Comment: I assume you have already read the lines from your text files and stored it in a list. After that you can use for loop to iterate through each line and use slicing to extract as many characters as you want.

Comment: Please show an example of the file content and explain the alignment in the output

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in text.split("<"):
    if x != '':
        print(f'<{x[:6]}')
```

This might help

Answer (score 0):

Using regex

```
import re

txt = '<1 acloclscloclxcccdddddddddddcccccddddddddddddweeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee <2 lsjfljljljljljljlsjdfojljljlholhowljljljljouopuljlj <3 ljlhohouojljljjouopuljljljhlhouljljlhh <4 hououojljljlhouojljljljlhouljljljljoukhklhkhkh'

print(re.findall('(<[\s\S]{0,6})', txt))
```

Output -

```
['<1 aclo', '<2 lsjf', '<3 ljlh', '<4 houo']
```